# XMLHttpRequest, using more than 1 wont work, just the first on. need to use more than one

Tags: javascript

Why in this code it only loads the first script? the ones next wont load for some reason, i tried different combinations and nothing works, i have tried to change the variable names, the values inside the code, but nothing makes the code work. What should i change to make the script work again and again? like a loop.

```
<label for="img1" class="container1">
     <img src="img/cover/1.jpg" alt="" class="container1">
     <div>
     <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img-descr">
     <div>
         <p id="Title1"></p>
         <p id="Runtime1"></p>
         <p id="Plot1"></p>
         <script>
             var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
             xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                 if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
                    var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime, plot: fullMovie.Plot,};
                    document.getElementById('Title1').innerText = movie.title;
                    document.getElementById('Runtime1').innerText = movie.runtime;
                    document.getElementById('Plot1').innerText = movie.plot;
                    }
                    };
                    xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3322364&plot=short&r=json", true);
                    xhttp.send();
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</label>
<label for="img2">
    <img src="img/cover/2.jpg" alt="" class="container1">
    <div>
        <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img-descr">
        <div>
            <p id="Title2">Title2</p>
            <p id="Runtime2">Title2</p>
            <p id="Plot2"></p>
            <script>
                var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhttp2.readyState == 4 && xhttp2.status == 200) {
                        var fullMovie2 = JSON.parse(xhttp2.responseText)
                        var movie2 = { title2: fullMovie2.Title, runtime2: fullMovie2.Runtime, plot2: fullMovie2.Plot,};
                                        document.getElementById('Title2').innerText = movie2.title2;
                document.getElementById('Runtime2').innerText = movie2.runtime2;
                document.getElementById('Plot2').innerText = movie2.plot2;
                }
                };
                xhttp2.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1528854&plot=short&r=json", true);
                xhttp2.send();
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

Comment: Call the second xhr with the callback on success(200) of the first xhr.

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: Hmm.. you have `var xhttp` twice on the same page...wouldn't the second `var xhttp` reassign everything to the second `xhttp`like overriding the first one? Try giving each one a unique variable name like `xhttp1` and `xhttp2`

Comment: No, changed all xhttp to xhttp2, but doesnt work

Comment: Did you change it in all 7 areas? That's xhttp2 in the last seven places of the script

Comment: yes, updated the code im running on the post

Comment: Can you make what you have working so far on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working, please review my answer, sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, they both work now. I made them both into IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression). See [Ben Alman's article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

```js
(function() {

  xHR();

  function xHR() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
        var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
        var movie = {
          title: fullMovie.Title,
          runtime: fullMovie.Runtime,
          plot: fullMovie.Plot,
        };
        document.getElementById('Title1').innerText = movie.title;
        document.getElementById('Runtime1').innerText = movie.runtime;
        document.getElementById('Plot1').innerText = movie.plot;

        xHR();

      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3322364&plot=short&r=json", true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
})();

(function() {

  xHR2();

  function xHR2() {
    var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp2.readyState == 4 && xhttp2.status == 200) {
        var fullMovie2 = JSON.parse(xhttp2.responseText)
        var movie2 = {
          title2: fullMovie2.Title,
          runtime2: fullMovie2.Runtime,
          plot2: fullMovie2.Plot,
        };
        document.getElementById('Title2').innerText = movie2.title2;
        document.getElementById('Runtime2').innerText = movie2.runtime2;
        document.getElementById('Plot2').innerText = movie2.plot2;

        xHR2();
      }
    }
    xhttp2.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1528854&plot=short&r=json", false);
    xhttp2.send();
  }
})();
```

```html
<label for="img1" class="container1">

  <div>
    <input id="img1" type="radio" name="img-descr">
    <div>
      <p id="Title1"></p>
      <p id="Runtime1"></p>
      <p id="Plot1"></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<label for="img2">
  <div>
    <input id="img2" type="radio" name="img-descr" class="container1">
    <div>
      <p id="Title2">Title2</p>
      <p id="Runtime2">Title2</p>
      <p id="Plot2"></p>

    </div>
  </div>
</label>
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/EPbjMU8AQVPi3RtfMCuv?p=preview im trying to get the description under the image when you click over the img

Comment: So...the snippet works? Both are functioning as your post requested, correct?

Comment: the snippet works, but not in my code. i know its crap but im not programmer just for hoby

Comment: ill check the answer soon

Comment: If your OP (Original Post) is resolved, accept the appropriate answer, then ask a new question referencing this one.

Comment: I'm already looking at your Plunker...I'll try to help...it doesn't look so hard just cluttered a bit.

Comment: thanks man! i think the bitfiddler answer should help for automation for adding "new movies". should that code work?

Comment: You were missing a tag end of a `</div>` , it works now. I also finished #3 and #4, placed all script in `script.js` and all styles in `style.css`. These external files will be located in the left section. http://plnkr.co/edit/A6Jq3lHxchQLaS0IZMsF?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You should cleanup your code so that you have a single function that is called in each place you want to get values. You could have a script in the header section of your html with a function something like:

```
getMovieData( moveID, titleID, runtimeID, plotID ) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
       var fullMovie = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText)
       var movie = { title: fullMovie.Title, runtime: fullMovie.Runtime, plot: fullMovie.Plot,};
       document.getElementById(titleID).innerText = movie.title;
       document.getElementById(runtimeID).innerText = movie.runtime;
       document.getElementById(plotID).innerText = movie.plot;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" . movieID . "&plot=short&r=json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Then call that in each of your tags. It's cleaner and will scale better and should eliminate your bug.

Comment: thats was the first think i tried to do... how do i call each movie?

Comment: Use a call like: getMovieData( 'tt128854', 'Title1', 'Runtime1', 'Plot1')

Comment: how do i replace the movieID inside the xhttp.open

Comment: so how can i call the getMovieData, think i have a div tag with the tt128854 id, so how can i make the script be run and fill the title runtime and plot?

Comment: Just like in my example above. Replace the code in your script tags with a call like that. You can get the div tag id and put that in the function call. There are better ways to structure your code, but that would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors.

- There is an errant "}" just above the last `</script>` tag.
- There were a few mislabeled variables
  and most importantly
- the xhttp variables were clobbering each other.

bitfiddler is right that you should extract the script out into a separate file.

Ignoring the html, here is working code, based upon your code, that fixes the items listed above:

```
                            <p id="Title1"></p>
                            <p id="Runtime1"></p>
                            <p id="Plot1"></p>
                            <script>
                                var xhttp1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhttp1.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                    if (xhttp1.readyState == 4 && xhttp1.status == 200) {
                                        var fullMovie1 = JSON.parse(xhttp1.responseText)
                                        var movie1 = { title1: fullMovie1.Title, runtime1: fullMovie1.Runtime, plot1: fullMovie1.Plot};
                                        document.getElementById('Title1').innerText = movie1.title1;
                                        document.getElementById('Runtime1').innerText = movie1.runtime1;
                                        document.getElementById('Plot1').innerText = movie1.plot1;
                                    }
                                };
                                xhttp1.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3322364&plot=short&r=json", true);
                                xhttp1.send();
                            </script>

                            <p id="Title2"></p>
                            <p id="Runtime2"></p>
                            <p id="Plot2"></p>
                            <script>
                                var xhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                                xhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
                                    if (xhttp2.readyState == 4 && xhttp2.status == 200) {
                                        var fullMovie2 = JSON.parse(xhttp2.responseText)
                                        var movie2 = { title2: fullMovie2.Title, runtime2: fullMovie2.Runtime, plot2: fullMovie2.Plot};
                                        document.getElementById('Title2').innerText = movie2.title2;
                                        document.getElementById('Runtime2').innerText = movie2.runtime2;
                                        document.getElementById('Plot2').innerText = movie2.plot2;
                                    }
                                };
                                xhttp2.open("GET", "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt1528854&plot=short&r=json", true);
                                xhttp2.send();
                            </script>
```

Comment: Sorry about the wacky indentation. I don't have the patience to unindent each line ;)